# How to create skype like message window?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nslayoutmanager

I am just trying to design skype like message window , for this I have taken the NSDrawer element. It contains : a table view on left, menu items on top, text field on right bottom and text view at central portion on right side. Using text view I can play with string being displayed but I cannot draw the line between messages or round rectangle surrounding user name and time stamp.

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve same look and feel for central message view as in skype?? or is there any better control then NSTextView to be used for it??

Thanks, for any suggestion...
Miraaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Adium instant messaging app is open source, why not see how they've done it?

http://trac.adium.im/wiki/GettingAdiumSource

Comment: ok... Thanks for your reply, I will definitely see it. However I was thinking that I will require NSLayoutManager class to perform this task!